# Cascade delete TYPO3 inline records don't work

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

I have a TYPO3 extension for some products which uses inline records to add documentgroups to a product. Deleting the product should also delete the documentgroups (inline records).

The documentation says `behaviour.enableCascadingDelete` is set to `true` by default, but the documentgroups are not deleted. Setting this value in the TCA does not make a difference.

```
'documentgroups' => [
    'exclude' => 1,
    'label' => $ll . ".documentgroups",
    'config' => [
        'type' => 'inline',
        'allowed' => 'tx_product_domain_model_docgroup',
        'behaviour' => [
            'allowLanguageSynchronization' => true,
            'enableCascadingDelete' => true,
        ],
        'foreign_table' => 'tx_product_domain_model_docgroup',
        'MM'            => 'tx_product_mm',
        'MM_match_fields' => [
            'tablenames' => 'tx_product_domain_model_docgroup',
            'fieldname' => 'documentgroups',
            'table_local' => $tableName,
        ],
        'foreign_sortby' => 'sorting',
        'minitems' => 0,
        'maxitems' => 99,
    ]
],
```

Comment: That's probably because you use an MM relationship. With MM it's technically possible that your docgroup records have back references to other records, so deleting them might not be reasonable. Just a guess though.

Comment: Hi @Nitori, after some debugging I can confirm your guess. If it's an MM relation cascading delete will not work. This can be verified by looking into `\TYPO3\CMS\Core\DataHandling\DataHandler->deleteRecord_procBasedOnFieldType` and ``\TYPO3\CMS\Core\DataHandling\DataHandler->getInlineFieldType`

Answer (score 1):

`enableCascadingDelete` has no effect on MM related tables. In `\TYPO3\CMS\Core\DataHandling\DataHandler->deleteRecord_procBasedOnFieldType` the inline type is checked and only if it's of type `field` (`foreign_field` must be set in the TCA) or `list` (`MM` and `foreign_field` must not be set in TCA) child entries will be deleted.