# TYPO3 Delete entry in MM relation table when deleting foreign or local records

Tags: typo3

In TYPO3 9 I have added another "category" to Fe-User. The connection is made via a mm-relation. If I delete an FE-User record or a Category record via backend, I want the entry in the mm-table to be deleted as well. How do you do that?

Answer (score 0):

If there is a regular mm relation configured in TCA the dependent records should be deleted too if you delete a record in the BE (with the data manager).

Be aware that 'deleted' records in TYPO3 are not removed from the database table but only get a `deleted` flag. they will no longer be shown in BE or FE. The same for any relations between deleted records.

You can use the `recycler` to revive a record and then the relations are needed too.

On the other hand there is a scheduler task to remove 'deleted' records from the database table. But that needs some configuration (which tables after which time should be 'cleaned') and will not free memory on most database systems.

Comment: Yes, is a regular mm relation configured in TCA, but the mm-record will stay, even I delete via recycler. 
I want the relations to be removed even if only deleting is done via the backend.

Comment: usually mm relations are really deleted, they never have a deleted flag,

Comment: I was also able to reproduce the behavior under TYPO3 10 and tx_news. If I assign a tag to an article and then delete the news and/or the tag, the entry in the tx_news_domain_model_news_tag_mm is retained. Even if you completely delete the data records via the recycler (backend or scheduler).

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to use one of the DataHandler hooks and do it yourself.

MM table records are imho not deleted, see here (for TYPO3 9.5): https://github.com/TYPO3/typo3/blob/d3d8bc04fd3a72780d6d653832c78e7f24b89b58/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/DataHandling/DataHandler.php#L5491

Here's another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56897849/cascade-delete-typo3-inline-records-dont-work) that's related.

Answer (score 0):

We solved this using the processCmdmap_deleteAction hook.